# When running a Mule Functional Test Case, is there a way to view the log output from the mule flow?

Tags: mule

I'm running a mule functional test case, and would like to see the output of my logger components from within the flow from the console.  Is there a way to do this?  Unfortunately, all I can see are the outputs from my loggers from within java components that I have built, but not the mule logger components themselves.  I'm happy to include any code or files as requested, but I don't think they are necessary to answer this question.

Answer (score 1):

by default when running Functional Test Case only error level logs will be shown.

You can place a log4j2 configuration file (xml) in the classpath to override this. Bear in mind his will work only since Mule 3.6.2.

HTH